# Regex match word only if it does not follow another word

Tags: regex, match, cpu-word, lookbehind

Using Regex, how can I match a word only if it does not follow another word?

e.g.
I want to match the word "dog" if the word "cat" does not appear before it

`the fox jumps over the dog` - Match
`a cat cannot jump over a big dog` - No Match
`Hello dog, I'm cat` - Match
`Hello cat, I'm dog` - No Match

I have tried the following:
`(?<!cat.*)dog`

However the quantifier inside the negative lookbehind does not work.

A solution to this would be greeeaaatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, negative lookbehinds have to be fixed size in most regexp engines, so you can't have `.*` there.

Comment: Checkout https://regex101.com/

Comment: If `\K` is supported `^[^c\r\n]*(?:c(?<!\bc(?=at\b))[^c\r\n]*)*\b\Kdog\b` https://regex101.com/r/gG2jZe/1 Else you might use a capture group https://regex101.com/r/4Hd85F/1

Answer (score 0):

In PCRE with support for [Atomic Group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), [Conditionals](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) and [\K](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html), below regex can help in matching.

**Pattern:** `(?>^.*?\K(?:cat|(dog)))(?(1)|$.^)`

**Breakdown:**

- `(?>^.*?\K(?:cat|(dog)))`

  - `(?:cat|(dog))` : match cat or a dog. `cat` is given precedence. If `dog` is matched, capture it in `group 1`.
  - `^.*?\K(?:cat|(dog))`: match lazily everything from `^` till `cat` or a `dog`. Use `\K` to discard string matched here.
  - `(?>^.*?\K(?:cat|(dog)))`: Enclose it in atomic group, `(?>)`, so backtracking is prevented. So in  case cat was matched first in the string, engine will not backtrack to match dog.
- `(?(1)|$.^)`: If group 1 matched, *then* branch is null so match is success, else try to match with impossible pattern `$.^`

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/omsG46/1/

Thanks

Comment: You sure do know your stuff! Thanks!