# Regex match ALL patterns only if they does not follow another pattern

Tags: r, regex

This question is closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350686/regex-match-word-only-if-it-does-not-follow-another-word).

I need a regex to match all dogs not preceeded by a cat:

```
jump dog1 cat                - Would match dog1
jump cat run dog1            - Would not match dog1, because it is preceeded by cat
jump dog1 dog2               - Would match dog1 and dog2
jump dog1 dog2 cat run dog3  - Would match dog1 and dog2, and would not match dog3 because it is preceeded by cat
```

I tried regex `(?>^.*?\K(?:cat|(dog(1|2|3))))(?(1)|$.^)`, but it does not work ([check out here](https://regex101.com/r/3MFdhs/1)):

```
jump dog1 cat                - Good
jump cat run dog1            - Good
jump dog1 dog2               - Bad, it needs to match _dog1 and _dog2
jump dog1 dog2 cat run dog3  - Bad, it needs to match _dog1, _dog2 and not _dog3
```

I also tried the simpler regex `(?>^.*?\K(?:cat|(\bdog(1|2|3))))` to get the dogs in group 1, but it didn´t work.

Any thoughts on this? I use R PCRE. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match

```
\bdog\w*|\bcat\b.*\K
```

and discard zero-width matches.

---

[PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/HsqMpE/1)

```
\bdog\w*   match 'dog preceded by a word boundary and followed by zero
           or more word characters
|          or
\bcat\b    match 'cat' bracketed by word boundaries
.*         match zero or more characters other than line terminators,
           as many as possible (greedy match)
\K         reset start of reported match and discard any characters
           matched previously
```

---

One variant of this idea is to match

```
\b(dog\w*)|\bcat\b.*
```

and consider only captures.

Another is to match

```
\bdog\w*|\bcat\b.*
```

and consider only matches that do not begin with 'cat'

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
\bcat\b.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\bdog\w*
(?s)\bcat\b.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\bdog\w*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/axLXE5/1). **Details**:

- `(?s)` - this inline modifier flag makes `.` match line break chars in a PCRE and ICU regex flavor (you do not need it with TRE (the default regex engine used with base R regex functions), but you cannot use TRE here)
- `\bcat\b.*(*SKIP)(*F)` - a whole word `cat` and then zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, and then fail the match (so as to start the search from the failure position, but since it is the end of the string here, there will be no other match here)
- `|` - or
- `\bdog\w*` - word boundary, `dog` substring, and then zero or more word chars.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/GMHm5V):

```r
x <- c("jump dog1 cat","jump cat run dog1","jump dog1 dog2","jump dog1 dog2 cat run dog3")
regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\bcat\\b.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\\bdog\\w*", x, perl=TRUE))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "dog1"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "dog1" "dog2"

[[4]]
[1] "dog1" "dog2"
```